# How to put Stripe first, PayPal second on the checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, paypal

On our [checkout](https://israel-escorts.com/en/checkout/) page we have PayPal first, after that Stripe. How to put Stripe first, PayPal second on checkout page?

[image: o]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your admin panel, go to `Woocommerce` > `Settings` > `Payments` tab > and drag the payment methods in the order you want.